# Mysql Use auto increment id from previous insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. I am trying to create a procedure that adds a user to the table `User` and then create a wallet using the Autoincremented id of the previous insert to set as userId in the wallet. Here is my procedure now:

```
BEGIN

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO User (username, email, password, role) VALUES (parUser, parEmail, parPassword, parRole);

INSERT INTO Wallet (userId, market, coin, quantity, avgPrice, startValue) VALUES (???, 'USDT', 'USDT', 2000.0, 1.0, 2000.0)

COMMIT;

END
```

But on the place of the `???` I need to place the auto_incremented `id` of the just inserted user.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is veeeery bad table structure then. Why not just set for `ID` column to be auto-increment? When ID is auto-increment, you don't need to provide number for ids.

Comment: @Marko Ivkovic  he needs the insert id from the first query to insert in the next query.

Comment: Yeah, but the Wallet needs to be connected to the User, so I need the User.id for the Wallet to connect right?

Comment: Use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the inserted autoincrement ID.

Comment: @Grumpy yeah that's right!

Comment: @TheImpaler I need to provide the table user then right? So the query knows I am talking about the last inserted id of the table User?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk No. It automatically retrieves the last ID inserted in the session. See Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general method captures the id using [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and then re-uses it:

```
INSERT INTO User (username, email, password, role)
    VALUES (parUser, parEmail, parPassword, parRole);

SET @userId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Wallet (userId, market, coin, quantity, avgPrice, startValue)
    VALUES (@userId, 'USDT', 'USDT', 2000.0, 1.0, 2000.0);
```

Comment: Yess, this worked! So if I understand correctly, the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` checks over all tables which record is inserted last and returns that ID?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk . . . Read the documentation, but it basically looks at the last `insert` in the session.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk `LAST_INSERT_ID()` may be used in second INSERT immediately, without intermediate variable usage. And pay attention - the queries must be executed in the same coonnection (especially when connection pool is used - in this case they must be sent as single batch).

Comment: @Akina . . . I always store such volatile values in a variable, probably due to my putting in debug statements in the middle (sometimes) that throws everything off.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree. My code is full of excess variables during creation/debugging too.